# Java type casting - float (and long) to int

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to understand the type casting in Java. I have read that  `long` is converted to `int` by using reduced modulo by range of `int` and `float` is converted to `int` by removing the fractional part.
I tried the following code.

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String arf[])
    {
        System.out.println((int)2147483648.0);
        System.out.println((int)2147483648L);
    }
}
```

...where 2147483647 is the maximum value of `int`.

The output is:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

When `float` is converted to `int` its fractional part is removed. So, `(int)2147483648.0` should also equal to `-2147483648`.

Can anyone explain to me why `2147483648.0` is cast to `2147483647`?

Comment: Isn't that actually a double type? To use float you should define the number as  2147483648.0f.

Answer (score 11):

2147483648.0 is actually 2<sup>31</sup>, whereas the maximum value for an `int` is 2<sup>31</sup>-1.  So, that floating point value is literally one value too high to fit.

The reason that it's going to truncate it to the highest int value is described [in the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) as a **narrowing conversion**.

> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or
>      int, as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
>    - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, **rounding
>        toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3)**. Then
>        there are two cases:
>    - If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long, then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>    - Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of the first step is the int value V.

The relevant part here is that the value will **round towards zero**.  So long as the floating-point value (or long) is above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, a cast to `int` will result in its highest value.  The same is true for a value that's lower than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as well.

Something curious happens if you use `(int)-214783649L`; it will suddenly become 214783647!  Why this happens is also explained in the JLS, emphasis mine:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards **all but the n lowest order bits**, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, **this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ** from the sign of the input value.

The long representation of that value in binary with a pipe denoting the 32-bit cut-off, looks like this:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 | 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

When a conversion happens, the first 32 bits are discarded, leaving you with the highest possible `int`.

The inverse is true with a positive long - the higher 32 bits contain all 1s which are discarded on a conversion.

The full structure is below, with pipe again denoting the 32 bit mark:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 | 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: I haven't been able to find a copy of IEEE 754 that isn't really expensive, but I doubt that IEEE 754 round-toward-zero is the important part. I'm pretty sure that part still produces `2147483648.0`. The important part is right after the part you quoted, where it describes what happens if the result still isn't representable in type T: "Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true: ... The value must be too large (a **positive value of large magnitude** or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long."

Comment: Rounding towards zero only applies when there is a fractional part. It doesn't explain how the 8 became 7.

Answer (score 8):

No matter which greater value (*than int max value*) you give as a `float` value, it cuts(fits) down to `int` max value which is `2147483647`

```
 System.out.println((int)2147483699.0); //2147483647
 System.out.println((int)3147483699.0); //2147483647
```

Edit :

Range of long in java is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive).` where as `-2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).`

So if your value of long is larger/lesser than the values given for an `int`,  conversion is never accurate.

Comment: what about the long? Could you please explain.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is the *smartass here*. If you observe the byte code carefully, you can see that the compiler is replacing the float value to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

So, like *Suresh* says, any float value above 2147483647.0 is replaced by 2147483647.

code :

```
public static void main(String arf[]) {
        int i = (int) 2147483649121.0f;
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println((int) 2147483648L);
    }
```

Byte code :

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: ldc           #16                 // HERE : int 2147483647
         2: istore_1      
         3: getstatic     #17                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         6: iload_1       
         7: invokevirtual #23                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
        10: getstatic     #17                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        13: ldc           #29                 // int -2147483648
        15: invokevirtual #23                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
        18: return
```

Answer (score 0):

Any integer greater than `2147483647` cause an overflow. Any assignment or casting in this cases produces negative max `int` -

look (int)2147483699L) is also produces `-2147483647`

```
System.out.println((int)2147483699L);
```

Answer (score 0):

int cannot display decimal.
Therefore, when casting, the float number omits the decimal point and represents only the absolute number.
This method  is narrow casting.